# Convert Web Application (ZF2) to PHAR

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, phar

I know how to convert php file into phar file.

```
$phar = new PHAR('app.phar');
$phar->addFile('file1.php');
$phar->addFile('file2.php');
```

I thought it can be useful only for converting POPO to PHAR.

**My question**

Is it possible to convert entire Zend framework 2 web application to PHAR file? if yes, then How?

(or)

How to package Zend framework2 web application into a package? (except .zpk(zend studio package file) file format)

---

***Updated: creating Phar from entire application***

**create-phar.php**

```
$basePath = /path/to/;
$path = /path/to/application;  
$phar = new Phar ('project.phar');    
$phar->buildFromIterator(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path)), $basePath);
$phar->setStub("<?php 
    Phar::webPhar('project', 'public/index.php');
       include 'phar://project/public/index.php';
       __HALT_COMPILER();
    ?>");
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
include 'project.phar';
?>
```

**Question:**

When i run index.php it do not redirect to actual public/index.php file instead it shows blank page on the browser. How can I resolve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15750913/generating-a-phar-for-a-simple-application) . Also IMHO packing whole app is not a good idea. Fist, in times of composer it will be harder to develop, and second - as far as I know `APC` doesn't support `phar`, so you will hit great performance bottleneck.

Comment: I like your question, this will be useful for developers that want to hide its code in order to deliver it to companies.

Comment: @BrunoQuintanaFleitas [Not really](http://php.net//manual/pl/phar.extractto.php)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I deploy [phorkie](https://cweiske.de/phorkie.htm) as a `.phar` file.

There are some things to consider:

1. Pack up all files in the `.phar` - php and static asset files (js, css, png, jpg), too. [I use phing](https://github.com/cweiske/phorkie/blob/90f0bc1550eb0e5291f215552b22143fbe5e9398/build.xml#L85) to do that. Do not forget the dependencies.
2. You need a *stub* file that runs `Phar::webPhar()` which takes care of sending out HTTP headers
3. Write your own `.htaccess` rewrite rule interpreter, because `Phar::webPhar()` does not do nice-path resolving on its own. I [did that already](https://github.com/cweiske/phorkie/blob/90f0bc1550eb0e5291f215552b22143fbe5e9398/src/stub-phar.php#L59).
4. Manually take care of sending out caching headers for static files
5. Hope that you (or your users) don't run into one of the `Phar::webPhar` bugs:

   1. [Symlinked files](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67071)
   2. [No HEAD, PUT or DELETE support](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51918)
   3. [Redirection loop with FPM](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67587) (already fixed in git)
6. Hope that your user's [web server handles `.phar` files](http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/phar-webserver.htm) (it will not; [neither Debian](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=639268) [nor Fedora](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1117140) ship that configuration)
7. Hope that the user's web server is correctly configured to handle `.phar` files with `PATH_INFO` appended (`/path/to/file.phar/foo/bar.png`), like in http://p.cweiske.de/122

---

Getting phorkie running from the `.phar` took me the evenings of two weeks. Now that it basically works it still is not a drop-phar-and-play solution, because the default configuration of web servers just doesn't play nice with `.phar`.

Comment: Hi cweiske, thanks for your response. and hope it can solve my problem.

Comment: I will accept your answer once i will create my own zf2 phar file.btw ++ for your answer

Comment: Hi @cweiske, can you help me to set stub for my create-phar.php file? and i updated my question please look into that